# Least Square solution for approximating a sequence

Tags: approximation, estimation, least-squares

Suppose I have a sequence of length N $a_1,...,a_N$

I want to approximate this sequence by $k^1,...,k^N$ 
where $k$ is my variable.

What is the least square solution of this?

is there a closed form solution for this?

Comment: This subject is rather broad. See for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting also http://web.iitd.ac.in/~pmvs/courses/mel705/curvefitting.pdf